# Need for virtual functions

Tags: c++

I was asked this very basic question in an interview recently.

Why do we need virtual functions or in that matter polymorphism?

I gave various answers from real time projects explaining how it works but could not  answer the very basic question pertaining to need.
My question is (or his qns was)

I am anyways going to do the below to call the appropriate functions:

```
<base class> b = new <derived class>;
b.foo();

//can also be implemented as
<derived class> d = new <derived class>();
d.foo();
```

This above is not run time decision, as in I know while writing my code that I am going to put which type of derived object into base. The above can also be implemented directly as shown above. So why virtual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example shows that you need virtual functions (or polymorphism in general) for objects to behave depending on runtime parameters.

```
animal* cute = nullptr;

animal_type type = get_animal_type_from_user_input();
// ^ Value depends on user input at runtime, unless we have some crystal ball
//       or time machine, we won't know what type of animal it would be

if(type == cat) {
   cute = new cat;
}
else if(type == dog) {
   cute = new dog;
}

cute->fuss();   // Depends if cat or dog; we won't know until runtime
```

Comment: But you could not use any derived properties using base pointer cute, which is not inherited.

Comment: @Subhajit Basically the point. The purpose of the base class is to provide a common set of methods that can be and would be inherited and overridden by derived classes. You access the `cat` or `dog` through an `animal` pointer because in that way we can safely call `animal` methods and the behavior would still be what the derived class defines. Accessing the derived parts would, however, require casts and mostly horrid things that are best left if you're very sure on what you're doing.

Comment: @Subhajit Something really has to give and sacrifice if we use the flexibility of polymorphism. Loss of type information, often the use of dynamic allocation and other disadvantages, and that's our job as programmers to weigh the pros and cons of some technique if we're to use them.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that sounds correct. Your explanation is similar to implementation of abstract factory/factory pattern.  If possible can you give a little more information on the last comment you made (on loss of type info and dynamic allocation) .

Comment: @sahana You lose type information because after you've assigned a `cat` or a `dog` to an `animal` pointer, what you have left is the type information that it is an animal, but you'll not know based on the type alone (`animal`) whether it is originally a `cat` or a `dog`. Dynamic allocation because you use dynamic allocation because it is only determined at runtime whether the animal is a cat or a dog, and determining the how much to allocate at compile time would be impossible because cat and dog may have different sizes, and whether you want a cat or dog depends at runtime.

Comment: @MarkGarcia When I assign a cat object to animal isn't the animal object holding a cat pointer, and would that not be enough in determining the type of the object? I am sorry these could sound like very basic questions to you!!

Comment: @sahana No problem. As said, you only have one information, that is the `animal` pointer. As shown in the example, the only time you have the type information for the cat or the dog is when you allocate them (`new cat` / `new dog`). After the returned pointer is assigned to an `Animal*`, you lose that information.

Comment: @MarkGarcia So when we do "animal_type type = get_animal_type_from_user_input();"the cat pointer looses its identity!! that was a new learning! Could you suggest any book/site that has these sort of detailed explanation. Thanks so much for the patience and help!!

Comment: @sahana It's not really true to say that it loses its identity, because it's still possible to use `dynamic_cast` to get back a `cat*` from an `animal*` that happens to be a `cat`. But this uses something called *run-time type information*, and has an associated runtime cost and storage overhead. Nothing comes for free, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions are required when you want to override the behaviour of a method in base class with a method from child class at runtime via pointer of a base class. Very good example/samples here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13885/

Answer (score 0):

The various forms of polymorphism let the same (higher-level client/algorithmic) code process data of different types.  For example, writing code for a container that can store any type of data, or to sort any type of container, or to calculate pay for any type of employee or contractor.  Runtime polymorphism (virtual functions) lets you do this when the data's not known until runtime.